# Como remover apenas os espaços entre as palavras/letras?

Tags: python-3.x, string

Supondo que eu tenha uma a string: `str = ' p s i c ó l o g o '`. Reparem que a string tem um espaço antes das letras, um espaço entre as letras e um espaço depois das letras. O que eu quero é que os espaços entre as letras desapareçam, mas o espaço que está antes e o que está depois das letras permaneça. A string ficaria assim: `str = ' psicólogo '`. Eu até tentei o `str.replace(" ", "")`mas isto também eliminaria os espaços que estão antes e depois das letras, ficando assim: `'psicólogo'`

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar Expressões Regulares para eliminar apenas os espaços que existam entre palavras. Para isso você pode usar `\b` para casar com o limite das palavras ([veja documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters)).

Então se fizermos uma regex para casar 1 ou mais espaços que estejam entre duas palavras, a regex casará com todos os espaços da string exceto os iniciais e finais.

Com isso temos a regex `\b +\b` e agora basta usar [`regex.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.sub) para substituir os espaços achados por uma string vazia.

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r"\b +\b")
regex.sub("", "    p  s  i   c  ó   l   o   g    o    ")
# '    psicólogo    '
```

<sup>[Repl.it com o código rodando.](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-491324-6333)</sup>

Comment: Poderia explicar o motivo do voto negativo? Essa solução funciona.

Answer (score 2):

É possível criar uma expressão regular que capture apenas os espaços contido entre dois caracteres.

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"(?<=\w)\s+(?=\w)")
print(regex.sub("", "    p  s  i   c  ó   l   o   g    o    "))
```

A expressão `(?<=\w)\s+(?=\w)` pode ser lida assim:

- `\s+` capture um mais espaços tal que...
- `(?<=\w)` ...esses espaços sejam precedidos por um caractere...
- `(?=\w)` ...e que esses espaços sejam sucedidos por um caractere.

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser que exista **sempre** um espaço no início e outro no fim, pode simplesmente concatenar os espaços com aquilo que tentou, ou seja, `" " + str.replace(" ", "") + " "`.